# Absolute Div Fill Remainder of Window

Tags: css, layout, css-position

I have 3 divs, all positioned: absolute, but the div I want to fill the width of the window will only adapt to the length of the text within it. I want the yellow div #help to fill the remainder of the window.

I know this sounds noob but I cannot find the solution anywhere.

```
<div id="tab1">tab1</div>
<div id="tab2">tab2</div>
<div id="help">help</div>

    #tab1 {position: absolute;
    bottom; 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}


#tab2 {position: absolute;
    bottom; 0px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#help {position: absolute;
    bottom; 0px;
    right: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FBWzX/

Comment: The yellow div is not `#help`. So which one should fill what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `#help` to stretch, you can set the `left` and `right` values at the same time. This trick also works with `top` and `bottom`. Absolute positioned elements are quite flexible.

```
#help {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FBWzX/1/)

Comment: Ah yes help is red. Thanks @bažmegakapa! Helpful to know you can use both.